# How to import pts file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pts

I have a `pts` file with 2d points (x,y) that looks like this:

```
version: 1
n_points: 5
{
159.128 108.541
230.854 109.176
164.841 179.633
193.404 193.597
192.769 229.143
}
```

How can I read this file and import this data into variables in Matlab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would do it like that

```
 FileId=fopen(Filename)
 npoints=textscan(FileId,'%s %f',1,'HeaderLines',1)

 points=textscan(FileId,'%f %f',npoints{2},'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1,'Headerlines',1)
 % now you have the values you want you can put them in a matrix or any variable
 Y=cell2mat(C);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I though there is native function to open this file. Your need to change in your code this line: `points=textscan(FileId,'%f %f',npoints{2},'MultipleDelimsAsOne',2,'Headerlines',2);` and this `Y=cell2mat(points);`

Comment: @Guy well you can try importdata

check this link http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/ways-to-import-text-files.html